# Phrases with "To work"

Tags: expressions

Can I say this? I am not sure about the two phrases with "to work"

"my aspiration is to live and study in a pluralistic environment and, then, **to work towards** a career **in working with** the main global players **in world and European affairs**"

Comment: I think the redundancy in the sentence indicates that you're overthinking it - you're presenting your goal in a way that sounds like typical overwrought business language. It will probably be easier to read if you write more simply and straightforwardly. The repetition of "working"/"career"/"working" is redundant, "global"/"world" is redundant. Perhaps "... to begin a career involving (or "alongside") the main players in global and European affairs." is the clear and concise way to express this.

Comment: First step: Chop your sentence into two or more sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Either phrase in itself is fine, but some native English speakers will dislike the repetition of the verb. Others won't care, it's very subjective. If you want to play safe, I think you can easily replace the first "work with" by something else. Strive towards, develop, commit myself to, the possibilities are legion.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem a touch unwieldy. Perhaps trimming it a bit?

"my aspiration is to live and study in a pluralistic environment and, then, to have a career working with the main global players in world and European affairs"

Alternatively, 'begin' rather than 'have' is a good substitute if you want to a closer synonym to 'working towards'.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the difficulty is that the sentence conveys no information. How could you NOT work in a 'pluralistic environment', if you mean a place with more than one person in it? Who, exactly, are the players in global affairs? Decide what you mean, and then write it down.